# Dineen's Probability in Finance: A question on limiting behaviour of expectations of sequences of positive integrable random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

In the above book (first edition), the author proves the following theorem:

> If $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(Y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are increasing sequences of **positive integrable** random variables on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ and if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n$$ almost surely, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\lbrack X_n\rbrack = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\lbrack Y_n\rbrack.$$

In course of the proof, the author needs to prove, among other things, that $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega) = \lim_{n\to\infty} X_{n}^{\lbrack j_n \rbrack}(\omega)$ for every $\omega \in \Omega,$ where $X^{\lbrack m \rbrack}$ denotes the $m-$th truncation of $X$ and $j_n$ is a certain previously defined strictly increasing ($j_{n+1} > j_n$) sequence of natural numbers. Here, he distinguishes two cases: 1) in case $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_{n}(\omega) < \infty,$ we have $X_{n}(\omega) < j_n$ for every $n$ bigger than certain $n_0$ so that we plainly have (due to the definition of $X^{m}(\omega)$) that $X_{n}^{\lbrack j_n \rbrack}(\omega) = X_n(\omega)$ for all $n \geq n_0.$ 2) In case $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_{n}(\omega) = \infty,$ he says:

> for all $n,$ we have either $X_{n}(\omega) - X_{n}^{\lbrack j_n \rbrack}(\omega) \leq 1/2^{j_n}$ or $X_{n}^{\lbrack j_n \rbrack} = j_n.$ Since $j_n \geq n,$ we have, in either case, $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n^{\lbrack j_n \rbrack} = \infty.$

This would clearly establish the claim that $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega) = \lim_{n\to\infty} X_{n}^{\lbrack j_n \rbrack}(\omega)$ but I have a couple of questions here:

- First, from where does it follow that $$X_{n}(\omega) - X_{n}^{\lbrack j_n \rbrack}(\omega) \leq 1/2^{j_n}$$ and for what $n'$s is it true? My guess is that it has something to do with pointwise convergence of the truncations $X^{\lbrack m \rbrack}$ to $X$ for $m \to \infty$ (this seems obvious).
- Second, why is it not enough to say: if $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) = \infty,$ then $X_{n}^{\lbrack j_n \rbrack} = j_n$ for $n$ big enough and since $j_n \geq n,$ we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}X_{n}^{\lbrack j_n \rbrack} = \infty$ and we ar done (does it have sth in common with the fact that $j_n$ depends on $n$?)

Comment: @Math1000: I am not saying the theorem is not rigorous, I just do not understand one tiny detail of its proof. This detail is somehow captured in my questions above. And yes, it uses truncations, if only implicitly: they are defined on p. 123 in the first edition.

Comment: @Math1000: maybe you are referring to a similar theorem dealing with positive bounded random variables only, whereas the theorem I am referring to deals with positive integrable RVs?

Comment: Ah, indeed I had the wrong theorem; the one I was looking at states "increasing sequences of simple positive random variables." I will delete my previous comments.

Comment: In the proof of the (correct) theorem, the author still is not using the aforementioned truncations, but instead the "canonical sequence" of simple random variables $\{X_n\}$ defined explicitly such that $|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|\leqslant 2^{-n}$ for all $n$ and $\omega$. I suggest you study the construction of the $X_n$ carefully.

Comment: @Math1000: Thank you, your response suggests that the second edition has a different proof. This raises the question whether the present "proof" is correct or not. I still wonder.

Comment: I don't have access to the first edition so there isn't enough context to answer that question. To my knowledge, though, the proof given in the second edition is the standard one, and it is probably equivalent to an argument using truncations.